# Javascript: Deep comparison of object function syntax error

Tags: javascript, function, object, syntax

I am writing a recursive function for doing a deep comparison of two objects. However, I am getting a syntax error.

this is the function:

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
    if (compareArrays(Object.keys(obj1), Object.keys(obj2))){
        for (let x of Object.keys(obj1)){
            if (typeOf obj1.x == 'object' && typeOf obj2.x == 'object')\
                        return deepEqual(obj1.x, obj2.x)
            else{
                if (obj1.x !== obj2.x) return false
            }
        }
            return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }

}
```

this is the function compareArrays(this has no errors):

```
function compareArrays(array1, array2) {
    if (array2.length === array1.length) {
        for (var i = array2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (array2[i] !== array1[i]){
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
}
    else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Expected output:
true/false
Actual output:

```
if (typeOf obj1.x == 'object' && typeOf obj2.x == 'object') return deepEqual(obj1.x, obj2.x)
                       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: `typeof` instead of `typeOf` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistyped `typeof` and also `\` is useless

Try this

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
    if (compareArrays(Object.keys(obj1), Object.keys(obj2))){
        for (let x of Object.keys(obj1)){
            if (typeof obj1.x == 'object' && typeof obj2.x == 'object')
                return deepEqual(obj1.x, obj2.x)
            else{
                if (obj1.x !== obj2.x) return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, can't believe I was so stupid XD. Also I just put the backslash in so that people wouldn't have to scroll on the stack overflow post. I don't actually have one in my program.

Comment: Glad to help :) Have a nice day